# Do I need ESTA if I have an I-94 in my passport?

Tags: esta, i-94, canadian-residents

I live in Canada and have an EU passport. I have a valid I-94 in my passport as I went to the US by car.
I am flying to the us from Canada and was not sure if I need to get ESTA.

Comment: I believe you need ESTA, but if you've been in Canada for less than 30 days, I am not 100% sure that you do, maybe more like 95%.  How long has it been since you left the US?

Comment: I left the States more than 30 days ago. Thanks